# R - calculate probability and flip x/y axis of cumulative curve (ECDF)

Tags: r, ecdf

In R I plot a cumulative curve using the ecdf function to show area vs. elevation. By default the elevation is plotted on the x axis, the area on the y axis, where elevation is given in total values (eg. 1000-3000m) and the area in probability (0.0-1.0).

- I would like to show elevation in percentage/probability values too.
- I would like to flip the axis and visualize area at x axis and elevation at y axis.

How can I do this? I could not find a solution.

This is my code:

```
library(rgdal)
setwd("G:/data")
raster <- readGDAL("elevation.tif")
plot(ecdf(raster$band1), main="Hypsometric curve")
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a small data set such that people can reproduce your problem? For example, scale down your `elevation.tif` to toy size (100x100 px or so), then execute `readDGAL` and use `dput` to convert the result in text form which you can paste here. You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just about any solution will begin by creating an array representing all vertices in the plot.**  They are obtained by extracting coordinates from the `ecdf` object.  To illustrate, let's generate some data.

```
n <- 32
k <- floor(n/2)
x <- 1 - runif(n)^2
x <- c(x, sample(x, k, replace=TRUE))
```

Here's the standard ECDF calculation and plot, for reference:

```
f <- ecdf(x)
plot(f, main="Default Plot")
```

[image: ECDF plot]

`R` prefers putting data into `data.frame` objects.  Here's one way.  Note how the range of data is expanded slightly in order to show the natural endpoints of the curve, which starts at a level of y=0 and ends at a level of y=1:

```
expand <- function(x, f=1.05, ...) {# Expand a data range
  r <- range(x, ...)
  (r - mean(r)) * f + mean(r) 
}
X <- with(environment(f), {
  x.range <- expand(x)
  data.frame(x=c(x.range[1], x), 
             xend=c(x, x.range[2]),
             y=c(0, y),
             yend=c(0, y))
})
```

With this convenient data structure `X` in place, all that remains is to describe the plot.  I use `ggplot2` for this:

```
library(ggplot2)
g.ECDF <- ggplot(X, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0:1, linetype=2, size=1.0, color="Gray") +
  geom_segment(color="#b0b0b0", size=0.8) +
  geom_point(data=X[-1,]) +
  xlab("Elevation") + ylab("Proportion of Total") + 
  ggtitle("Hypsometric Curve")

print(g.ECDF)
```

[image: ggplot2's version of the ECDF]

Now, for the *coup de grace*: simply tell `ggplot2` to switch the axes:

```
print(g.ECDF + coord_flip() + ggtitle("Axes Flipped"))
```

[image: Flipped ECDF]

Comment: Works perfectly fine!
Is it possible to add a second line to the graph and if yes, how?

Comment: Sure. The natural way using `ggplot2` is to append a data frame to the first one, using one more field to distinguish records in the two datasets.  See http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html for the details.